# DDL Generation For Db2 tables

Tags: java, javascript, sql, db2

I am working on a web project,where i will access Db2 table and display the contents of table.Now i am in need of generating the DDL schema of the tables when the users click "Generate DDL" option from the web page.Is there any command or JAVA API's to get the DDL of the Db2 tables?

Comment: Which DB2, LUW/IBM i/Z?  And what version?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my project http://code.google.com/p/db2-scheme2ddl/ for code samples.
I can get table DDL for IBM DB2 with pure JDBC.

In short,

1. Invoke undocumented DB2 function  CALL
   SYSPROC.DB2LK_GENERATE_DDL('-e -z SAMPLE', ?)
2. Store second INOUT
   parameter for later use
3. Find primary object's DDL with query

   select
       OP_SEQUENCE, SQL_STMT, OBJ_SCHEMA, OBJ_TYPE, OBJ_NAME, SQL_OPERATION
                               FROM SYSTOOLS.DB2LOOK_INFO where OP_TOKEN=? and OBJ_SCHEMA=? and OBJ_TYPE=? and OBJ_NAME=?

Answer (score 0):

You can use db2look to dump table ddl like this:

```
db2look -z <table schema> -d <database name> -noview -nofed -e -x -t <table name>
```